# CSS styles being applied to every element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with my CSS. When I apply any styles to h2, h3 of my jumbotron class, it gets applied to every other h2 and h3. 
Check my github repo below for the code.
http://usamahameed.github.io/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple one for beginners. Quick explanation;

If you define a tag overall like;

```
h1 {color:red;}
<h1>EVERY H1 tag will be RED</h1>
```

If you make it explicit with a `class` or `id` (Note: `id` will only apply to one object, `class` can be used multiple times to many objects) attribute set to distinguish the style just for that one object then it will ONLY apply to that object like;

```
.GreenH1 {color: green;}
#BlueH1 {color: blue;}

<h1 class="GreenH1">This H1 will be green</h1>
<h1 id="BlueH1">This H1 will be blue</h1>
```

Except that doesn't mean you have to make each one individually explicit. Say you want all the H1's in a panel to be one color, and all the H1's in another be a different color. Then you can specify it at the parent using a [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) like;

```
.OrangeH1s > h1 {color:orange;}
.PurpleH1s > h1 {color:purple;}

    <div class="OrangeH1s">
      <h1>One</h1>
      <h1>Two</h1>
      <h1>Three</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="PurpleH1s">
      <h1>One</h1>
      <h1>Two</h1>
      <h1>Three</h1>
    </div>
```

Here's a [CODEPEN TO PLAY](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNxQeQ) or use the Stack editor below.

```css
h1 {color:red;}

.GreenH1 {color: green;}
#BlueH1 {color: blue;}

.OrangeH1s > h1 {color:orange;}
.PurpleH1s > h1 {color:purple;}
```

```html
<h1>EVERY H1 tag will be RED</h1>

<h1 class="GreenH1">This H1 will be green</h1>
<h1 id="BlueH1">This H1 will be blue</h1>

<div class="OrangeH1s">
   <h1>One</h1>
   <h1>Two</h1>
   <h1>Three</h1>
</div>
        
<div class="PurpleH1s">
   <h1>One</h1>
   <h1>Two</h1>
   <h1>Three</h1>
</div>
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use style inside one element  `<h2 style="color:red;">tratata</h2>` or give element id and
assign style.